# grpc: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: golang, docker-compose, grpc

Всем привет!

Есть вот такой сервер https://github.com/3110Y/cc-profile/blob/init/cmd/main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/3110Y/profile/internal/infrastructure/di"
    "github.com/3110Y/profile/pkg/profileGRPC"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/grpclog"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    err := godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error loading .env file: %v", err)
    }
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("localhost:%s", os.Getenv("GRPC_PORT")))
    if err != nil {
        grpclog.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
    initializeDI, err := di.InitializeDI()
    if err != nil {
        grpclog.Fatalf("failed", err)
    }
    profileGRPC.RegisterProfileServiceServer(grpcServer, initializeDI.ProfileRPC)
    fmt.Println(grpcServer.GetServiceInfo())
    err = grpcServer.Serve(listener)
    if err != nil {
        grpclog.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
}
```

и есть вот такой клиент https://github.com/3110Y/cc-profile/blob/init/client/client.go

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/3110Y/profile/pkg/profileGRPC"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/insecure"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/grpclog"
)

func main() {
    conn, err := grpc.Dial("127.0.0.1:5300", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))

    if err != nil {
        grpclog.Fatalf("fail to dial: %v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    client := profileGRPC.NewProfileServiceClient(conn)
    request := &profileGRPC.ProfileWithoutIdSystemField{
        Email:      "testtesttest",
        Phone:      611,
        Password:   "Password",
        Surname:    "Surname",
        Name:       "Name",
        Patronymic: "Patronymic",
    }
    response, err := client.Add(context.Background(), request)
    if err != nil {
        grpclog.Fatalf("fail to client: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(response)
}
```

docker-compose https://github.com/3110Y/cc-profile/blob/init/docker-compose.yml

При попытке сделать запрос, выдает

```
2023/11/05 19:13:30 FATAL: fail to client: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5300: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."
```

код самого проекта https://github.com/3110Y/cc-profile/tree/init

Адреса совпадают,
в docker-compose проброс есть.

```
    ports:
      - ${GRPC_PORT}:${GRPC_PORT}
      - "40000:40000"
```

Не могу понять как поправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогло

Right-click on your PC
Properties
Advanced system settings
Environment Variables
Add new Variable: DOCKER_HOST
Value: tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
Run Docker Desktop
bottom-right, right-click on Docker-Desktop
Settings
Enable the following option: "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS"